# Check an Image URL is valid

Tags: typescript, react-native

My goal is to check an image source url to check whether it is valid or not. If it is valid, display the React Native Image as normal and if not, replace it with a local placeholder image. However, the following typescript function never seems to return anything and nothing is displayed.

```
renderImage(): JSX.Element {
    fetch(this.props.imageUrl)
    .then(res => {
      if(res.status == 404) {
        return (
          <Image
            source={require('../images/nasa-logo.png')}
            style={styles.imageThumbnail}
          />
        )
      } else {
        return (
          <Image
            source={{uri: this.props.imageUrl}}
            style={styles.imageThumbnail}
          />
        )
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return (
        <Image
          source={require('../images/nasa-logo.png')}
          style={styles.imageThumbnail}
        />
      )
    })

    return null // <-- skips to here
  }
```

Comment: you always are returning null. because you are running async call there

Comment: How do I add await/async to this function if I want to return a JSX Element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took Redwan Abbs answer as a template, but the issue with this is that the image can be stuck in a continuously rendering loop. The other answers are fine, they just take a lot more code to implement. I used the onError prop and used a boolean toggle to ensure it wasn't just getting continuously re-rendered.

```
    ...
    
    // state type declaration
    imageSrc: ImageSourcePropType
    imageError: boolean
    
    ...
    
    // state initialisation
    this.state = {
      imageSrc: {uri: this.props.imageUrl},
 

         imageError: false
        }
        
     ...
        
     onImageInvalid () {
       const placeholderImagePath: string = '../images/nasa-logo.png'
        
       if (!this.state.imageError) {
         this.setState({
           imageSrc: require(placeholderImagePath),
           imageError: true,
         });
       }
    }
        


    ...
    //render method
            
    <Image
      source={this.state.imageSrc}
      style={styles.imageThumbnail}
      onError={() => this.onImageInvalid()}
    />
```

Answer (score 9):

You don't need fech you can use onError fallback

```
    this.state = ({
     image:{uri: this.props.imageUrl}
    })
    const setimage = () => {
     this.setState=({image:  require('../images/nasa- 
   logo.png')  })
    }
    <Image
            source={this.state.image}
            style={styles.imageThumbnail}
             onError={()=>setimage()}
          />
```

PS: I am using my phone to answer, sorry for  bug if you found a typo and for the format

Answer (score 2):

I created an example component that should more or less do what you request

1. we keep a loading state, to indicate whether we are still check if the image exists
2. we keep a valid state: to indicate whether the imageUrl is valid
3. we initiate a fetch using `useEffect` and set the above states accordingly.

Only downside of this approach is that you will download the image twice if it exists: once the check for its existence, once by react-native to actually render the image

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';

import NasaImage from '../images/nasa-logo.png';

const ImageFallback = ({ imageUrl }) => {
  // start off in the loading state
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  // keep track whether imageurl returns valid result
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(null);

  // use effect to check for access to imageUrl,
  // run the effect when the component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(imageUrl).then(res => {
      setIsValid(res.status === 200);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);

  // if still loading or invalid: return fallback image
  if (loading || !isValid) {
    return <Image source={NasaImage} style={styles.imageThumbnail} />;
  }

  // return the image with the provided value
  return <Image source={{ uri: imageUrl }} style={styles.imageThumbnail} />;
};

export default ImageFallback;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just handle it with state

```
const [defaultImage, setDefaultImage] = useState(true);
// call this method inner componentDidMount
renderImage() {
    fetch(this.props.imageUrl)
    .then(res => {
      if(res.status == 404) {
        setDefaultImage(true);
      } else {
        setDefaultImage(false)
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      setDefaultImage(true)
    })
  }
   // use where u want
   const myImage = defaultImage? <Image
            source={require('../images/nasa-logo.png')}
            style={styles.imageThumbnail}
          /> : <Image
            source={{uri: this.props.imageUrl}}
            style={styles.imageThumbnail}
          />;
```